# Dynamic char field reading one char at the time

Tags: c++, dynamic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

char * text = new char;
scanf("%c", text);
scanf("%c", text+1);

return 0;
}
```

Sorry for this lame question... 
I'm trying to read a string one char at a time (because I need to check sth for every char..) 
For input "ab" the output is "ab" and a ?random? character...
It doesn't work without the 'scanf("%c", text+1);' either.. I can do this using static field, but this version gives me one extra char in the end.. What am I doing wrong? :'(

Comment: Just read a `std::string` and iterate through it (preferably with a standard algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

You allocate one `char` giving you the pointer `text`. You then access `text[0]` and `text[1]` which clearly give an out of bounds access. I strongly recommend you don't access memory explicitly and use a `std::string` instead, e.g.:

```
std::string text;
for (std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(std::cin), end; it != end; ++it) {
    // do whatever checks you need to do
    text.push_back(*it);
}
std::cout << "read '" << text << "'\n";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't realize I allocated pointer to just one char.. The problem is, we are forbidden to use std::string now, because we need to learn how to use pointers..
So the way I understand it, I need to allocate a field of certain length, and use it as long as the size is sufficient.. Right now it looks like this:   
    char * text = new char[10];
    scanf("%c ", text);
    cout << text << endl;
but I stil have the same problem, even if I try &text[0]... I'm accesing I out of the bounds again?